# Emails are not send in SFMC

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect

we had recently enabled Multi-Org and configured marketing connect in our Marketing Cloud instance. When we tried to send an email from both Marketing Cloud (using Salesforce Report) and Sales Cloud (Email Send), no emails are received. When we create a Journey the email is send to the same test contact. Can you please help me how to debug this. TIA.

Comment: Are you able to Import a SF report without issues? To troubleshoot, turn on logging in the Connector setup in SF, retry the send actions and then check the logs.

Comment: Are your Marketing Cloud users also integrated to Salesforce users? To enable correct sending to reports, campaigns, etc. make sure the integration & permissions in the CRM are also complete for individual users.